# DataTable Footer create through options?

Tags: jquery, datatable, footer

So I am creating a DataTable on the page with information grabbed from an ajax call.

```
//Initialize table
var table = $("#table").DataTable({
    deferRender: true,
    sDom: "t" +
        "<'dt-toolbar-footer' i " +
        "<'dataTables_info total'>" +
        ">" + "S",
    language: {
        searchPlaceholder: "Search",
        search: "_INPUT_" //no label
    },
    scrollY: 250,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: false,
    autoWidth: true,
    data: wholeData,
    aoColumns: columns,
    order: order,
    footerCallback: footerCallback
}); // END TABLE /////////////////
```

Cannot for the life of me figure out how to generate a footer within these options: [DataTable Options](https://www.datatables.net/reference/option/).

How do I create a footer *without* placing `<tfoot>` tags inside the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately DataTables does not currently have support for creating the footer inside the options. [DataTable Footer create through options](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/87461/#Comment_87461)

Although Allan suggests this problem will be looked at in future versions.

For now I just solved the problem by creating the `<tfoot>` DOM dynamically.

```
var footer = $("<tfoot></tfoot>").appendTo("#table");
var footertr = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(footer);

//Add footer cells
for (var i = 0; i < Columns.length; i++) {
    $("<td>" + Columns.FooterText + "</td>").appendTo(footertr);
}
```